# The condition of a matrix of rank 1 as a column times a row being diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra

If we multiply a column and a row, how to determine under what conditions the resulting matrix say $A$ is diagonalizable? I understand that if we multiply $u$ and $v^*$ for example, we get $A$ in the following shape where all the columns are some combinations of column vectors.

Ex: \begin{align*}
        u=\begin{bmatrix} u_1 \\u_2 \\ \vdots \\ u_n\end{bmatrix}, \qquad        v^*=\begin{bmatrix} v_1 & v_2 & \dots v_n \end{bmatrix} \\
    \end{align*}
Then: \begin{align*}
        u*v^*=\begin{bmatrix} u_1 \\u_2 \\ \vdots \\ u_n\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} v_1 & v_2 & \dots & v_n \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} u_1v_1&u_1v_2&\dots& u_1 v_n\\u_2v_1&u_2v_2&\dots&u_2v_n \\ \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots \\ u_nv_1&u_nv_2&\dots & u_nv_n\end{bmatrix}
    \end{align*}
However, I don't know how to determine under what conditions the resulting matrix is diagonalizable. I understand that this matrix is singular as all the rows can be eliminated to 0 except for the first row, how do I find out under what conditions it is diagonalizable? (multiplicity?) I think I am almost there but cannot figure out. Can someone help?

Comment: Isn’t it always diagonalizable? The zero eigenspace is never deficient, and since every eigenvalue has at least one eigenvector, this would mean that the one nonzero eigenspace is also not deficient either.

Comment: @user You asked [the same question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3796113/81360). Have you tried to make sense of my hint?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we're working over some algebraically closed field we can find the jordan form of $A$. Therefore, a necessary and sufficient condition for $A$ to be diagnolizable is for $A$ to have exactly one nonzero eigenvalue. This is true because if all of $A$'s eigenvalues are zero, and it has rank 1, it must be of the form $\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 & ...\\
0 & 0 & 0 & ...\\
... & 0 &  0& ...\\
\end{pmatrix}$
(one jordan block for 0 of size 2, and all other jordan blocks of size 1) which would mean A is definitely not diagnolizable. However if A has exactly one nonzero eigenvalue, and A is of rank one, the jordan form is $ \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & ... \\
0 & 0 &...\\
... & 0 & 0 & \\
\end{pmatrix}$ so $A$ is diagnolizable. Now: Since $A$ is zero if u or v are zero we can assume they are both nonzero. To figure out when $A$ has a nonzero eigenvalue we can take a unitary\orthogonal transformation to a new basis consisting of $\hat{u}$ as the first vector (where $\hat{u}$ is u normalized), where such a change of basis just conjugates $A$ by the change of basis matrix $P$, so $A \mapsto PAP^{T} = A'$. In this new basis $A'$ has 0 as all rows except the first, which is $(||u|| v'_1 , ... , ||u|| v'_n )$ (where $v'_i$ are the transformed coordinates of v). Thus it is obvious $A'$ (and so, A) has a nonzero eigenvalue iff $\langle u,v\rangle \neq 0$.